# Div grid cell-type alignment

Tags: html, css

I am aiming for a setup similar to this:

[image]

Unfortunately I end up with this:

[image]

Here are my specs:

I'm trying to get divs with an image to be set up without borders, and divs with text to have a 1 px border.

Here are the divs I set up:

```
<section id="row2">

    <div id="textBox1" class="column left">
        <p> TEXT BOX 1 </p> 
    </div> <!--#textBox1 .column.left-->

    <div class="column right">
                <img src="assets/top-right-image.png"/>
            </div>

</section> <!--#row2-->

<section id="row3">

    <div class="column left"><img src="assets/bottom-left-image.png"/></div>

    <div id="textBox2" class="column right">
        <p> TEXT BOX 2 </p>
    </div>

</section> <!--#row3-->
```

As you can see, I set up the text divs with an id "textBox1" and "textBox2". Unfortunately, this blows them up and makes the div.column.left in #row3 to align to the right.

here is the CSS:

```
.column {
     float: left;
     position: relative;
     margin: 20px 11px;
}

.left {
     width: 408px;
}

.right {
     width: 449px;
}

#bannerPic {
     padding: 0px 15px;
}

#row2 div {
     height: 352px;
}

#row3 div {
     height: 598px;
}

#textBox1 {
    border: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#textBox2 {
    border: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you tied to that particular mark-up, or are changes allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are the top two items are not the exact same height, so the 3rd item, the taller photo, is "hanging" on the first.  This happens because of the way float behavior works.  Make sure the parts of each row (the divs) are rendered to the exact same height, including all borders, margin, padding, etc.

The other option is to "clear" the section tags.  Since part of your content is text, this may be a lot easier.  It's probably easier anyway.  :)

```
section { clear: both }
```

Comment: What exactly did the "clear" property do there? It's incredibly hazy what http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp says...

Comment: Clear moves the flow down below any floating elements.  This means the next floated element will start on the edge you float it to.  For instance, if you float some elements to the left, making a row, and then you have an element with clear left, any additional floated elements move below the first set of floats.  It's tricky to explain without a good visual.  I tend to avoid w3schools anymore.  Check out this [elaborate tutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/) - one of the first items explains both floats and clears better than I can.  It's long but don't be intimidated.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a style cascade for:

```
section {
  clear: both;
}
```

to clear out the floats and reset each row to the margin.

Comment: This did the trick. Can you explain what exactly happened there?

Comment: It's probably related to the heights of the first two divs.  See my answer below.

Comment: Clear basically turns off floats.  As Surreal Dreams said, if the left item in the first row was even one pixel higher (including margin) that the 2nd item in that row then the first item of the second row will be caught up in the float.  Clear basically overrides the float and puts the element it is on back to the static position at the left margin of the page.